# Would IIS benefit from a multiple-core CPU for handling concurrent requests (cpu intensive)?

Tags: asp.net, iis, installation, cpu, webrequest

Ok, I don't know if I've formulated my question correctly, but I'm currently facing the following problem:

Some requests on our Asp.Net site are rather long (ie: 60s) and CPU intensive (file import/validation) and our IIS is hosted in a virtual machine with a single core assigned.

Currently, when such requests happen, all other concurrent requests seem to get queued until the prior "long and cpu intensive" request complete.

Would IIS benefit from another core?  Would this help responding to more concurrent requests?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

1. Each request is it's own HTTP request
2. Your operations do not block each other (intentionally or otherwise)
3. Your operations are not bound on something else (memory, network, disk, etc)

Then yes, absolutely.  IIS is highly parallel (through both multithreading and async I/O).